# Imagick: Combine 7 images on top of each other, all are same size so no positioning needed

Tags: php, imagick

I am using PHP imagick, how can I combine 7 images on top of each other? They are all same size so there is no need for positioning or adjusting.

I have all images in array like this:

```
$images = explode("c", $character);
$elements = array();
$elements[0] = $skins[$images[0]];
$elements[1] = $eyes[$images[1]];
$elements[2] = $hair[$images[2]];
$elements[3] = $mouth[$images[3]];
$elements[4] = $pants[$images[4]];
$elements[5] = $shoes[$images[5]];
$elements[6] = $torso[$images[6]];

try{
$pdf = new Imagick($elements);
$pdf->setImageFormat('png');
$pdf->writeImages('public/images/avatars/new.png', true);
}
catch(ImagickException $e){
    echo($e);
}
```

I tried the code above, but it outputs 7 different images instead of one combined.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.compositeimage.php

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.combineimages.php

`$pdf->combineImages($elements);`

I think that should to work, but i cannot prove it.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

```
$pdf->compositeImage($elements[$i], $elements[$i]->getImageCompose(), 0,0,imagick::MONTAGEMODE_FRAME);
```

this will do (y)